# How to update/change an order in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

So I've been fiddling with this for a while now and I can't wrap my head around how analytics does it's calculations on purchases when updating an order with new/changed products.

I'm utilizing the datalayer(dl) and push my purchase event to the dl, which GTM listens to via a trigger event, all standard so far.

```json
{
  "event": "purchase",
  "currencyCode": "SEK",
  "ecommerce": {
    "purchase": {
      "actionField": {
        "id": "123",
        "tax": 30.0,
        "action": "purchase"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "123",
          "price": "5.0",
          "brand": "brand",
          "category": "category",
          "quantity": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But then our customers has the ability to change their orders. So with a bit of research [On here](https://www.optimizesmart.com/fixing-duplicate-cancelled-test-orders-and-refunds-in-google-analytics/) I was able to defer that you can add products with a negative quantity on the existing order to remove products after a changed order.

So this resulted in, something not optimal but it works for the orders products atleast. In this case I want one more item of the same. So I do this:

```json
{
  "event": "purchase",
  "currencyCode": "SEK",
  "ecommerce": {
    "purchase": {
      "actionField": {
        "id": "123",
        "tax": newTax -= oldTax,
        "action": "purchase"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "123",
          "price": "5.0",
          "brand": "brand",
          "category": "category",
          "quantity": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "123",
          "price": "5.0",
          "brand": "brand",
          "category": "category",
          "quantity": -2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

And it works for everything except the total of the purchase. Since that's calculated based on the products in the order why doesn't that update automatically when I update the order? Do I need to send in the oldTotal -= newTotal as well or is there a delay in the recalculations in analytics?

Comment: Keep in mind that multiple transactions with the same id are internally still reported as separate transactions, so negative transactions might mess with metrics like conversion rate.  Since you have EEC you should use refunds rather than negative transactions. And I'm not sure to what extent GA does "recalculations" at all, even refunds are reported for the date they have been uploaded, not for the date of the transaction.

Comment: I tried using refunds at first, that worked fine and dandy as such as did a full refund for the revenue on the first order. The issue is that when I do a full refund on the first order with eg. 1 product of X, then the customer finishes his edit of the order and he decided he wants 2 of X that would instead put the amount of products sold for that order at 3 instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting it calculate the total revenue on its own, have you tried adding the total revenue, total tax and total shipping on your own. These fields are present in the `actionField` as follows:-

```
   "actionField": {
    "id": "123",
    "action": "purchase"
    'revenue': 'newRev - oldRev',   // difference of new revenue and old revenue
    'tax':'newTax - oldTax',         // difference of new tax and old tax
    'shipping': 'newShipping - oldShipping'    // difference of new shipping and old shipping
  },
```

Of course do add the products as well.
In the canned GA reports, it will automatically add the old revenue and the new revenue amounts and use that as the revenue total.

Comment: Hi in the future! I am not entirely sure but I think we solved it by doing a total refund on the order and using a version suffix on the orders themselves, so like id: 123-1, 123-2 etc. If I recall correctly I wanted to avoid sending revenue because being grumpy I wanted google to do calculations for us. Thanks anyway for the reply :D

Comment: Hi @Tevious! Sorry for reviving an old thread and thank you for chiming in. Wouldn't creating a version suffix give an incorrect ecommerce conversion rate in GA? Does GA still consider the suffixed orders as one order or counts it as a different order?

Comment: Hey @Kunal! Sorry I can't really help any further, that's beyond my scope of expertise :) In the product performance report it does seem it tracks refunds per product. I'm not at that customer any more but I think they exported the reports and did a x-match on the different versions of the same order. Hope you figure something out and have a happy new year!